# Pandas: Tidy up groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregation

I really struggle with tidying up the table into a "normal" dataframe again after having aggregated something.
I had a table like that (columns):

```
RnnSize     EmbSize     RnnLayer    Epochs  Alpha   Eval    Run     Result
```

So I calculated average and std of the Result column over multiple runs using that command:

```
df.groupby(["RnnSize", "EmbSize", "RnnLayer", "Epochs", "Alpha", "Eval"]).agg({'Result': ['mean', 'std']})
```

The output is a DataFrame like that:

```
                                                             Result
                                                             mean   std
RnnSize     EmbSize     RnnLayer    Epochs  Alpha   Eval
```

It looks a bit like three levels.

df.columns outputs the following multiindex:

```
MultiIndex([(   'index',    ''),
            ( 'RnnSize',    ''),
            ( 'EmbSize',    ''),
            ('RnnLayer',    ''),
            (  'Epochs',    ''),
            (   'Alpha',    ''),
            (    'Eval',    ''),
            (  'Result', 'std'),
            (  'Result', 'std')],
           )
```

How do I flatten that again, removing "Result" and putting mean and std into the same "level" as the rest?
There are so many commands like reset_index, drop_level and so on, but I did not find out yet how to fix that. It quite confuses me.

Edit: For reproducability, here is my entire code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfRuns = pd.read_csv("Results.csv", encoding="utf-8")
dfRuns

dfAv = dfRuns.copy()
dfAv = dfAv.groupby(["RnnSize", "EmbSize", "RnnLayer", "Epochs", "Alpha", "Eval"]).agg({'Result': ['mean', 'std']})
```

And the (shortened) csv file Results.csv:

```
RnnSize,EmbSize,RnnLayer,Epochs,Alpha,Eval,Run,Result
128,200,2,150,0.1,Precision,1,0.5940
128,200,2,150,0.1,Recall,1,0.5038
128,200,2,150,0.1,F1,1,0.5144
128,200,2,150,0.1,Precision,2,0.5851
128,200,2,150,0.1,Recall,2,0.4995
128,200,2,150,0.1,F1,2,0.5082
```

Comment: Will you please add the result of `print(df.columns)` to your question?

Comment: Added, thank you

Comment: According to your edit, there are two `std`s. Shouldn't one be `mean`?

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that as well, thats weird. I put in my original aggregation command, that one shouldnt actually produce two std columns?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a discrepancy among the code you ran, the code you posted, the output you got, and the output you posted. Any way, it doesn't matter much. The answer to this question will still be the same.

Comment: I just added my code and an example csv file for reproducability

Comment: Ok. Weird. Sorry. I just reopened the notebook and now the code works fine. Also no double column. That is weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then flatten the indexes:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.columns = [' '.join(col).rstrip() for col in df.columns.to_numpy()]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
df.groupby(["RnnSize", "EmbSize", "RnnLayer", "Epochs", "Alpha", "Eval"])['Result'].agg(['mean', 'std'])
```